# How to dynamically add text fields on Rails 4? (not nested)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, dynamic, form-for

I'm very new to Rails and I need to dynamically add/remove input fields on a "form_for" in Rails. I am using these inputs to alter a user's profile.

Here's the snippet I want to turn dynamic:

```
<%= f.label :languages, "Languages" %>
<%= f.text_field :languages, class: "shortInput", value: @parsed_json_user['user']['languages']%> <br />
```

I have seen many tutorials using nested attributes (I'm not even exactly sure about what those are) and such but I will not be using models. As you can see, I just want an object with a multitude of values (e.g. array) since I'll be using an API to update the "User" model.

I need something like:

Languages:
 English *remove*
 *add new*

Should I be using fields_for? Or somehow use JS or JQuery? Any help would be appreciated.

I searched everywhere for a similar question and haven't found any but if you actually know of or find one, pointing me in the right direction would be wonderful!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you need a text field for this? To me this looks like a select box. You can use select2 that is more interactive for multi select options.

Comment: I could use a select box for this but I think it would limit my users' choice. I will eventually do it as you suggested if I find no solution... Imagine someone can only speak Fula (or someother non-listed language). Not having it in the list would be a bummer. Thank you anyways for the suggestion!

Comment: In select2, there is an option to add new entries as well. Not just the ones that are already there.

Comment: this worked! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

@languages = User's Languages

```
 f.collection_select :user_languages[], @languages, :id, :name , {hide_label: true, :selected => @languages.first.id} , {:style => "width: 120px",:required => true}
```

Comment: having into account that @languages is an array of Strings, what should I call instead of "id" and "name"?

Comment: try not putting those 2 values

Comment: I managed to make it work but what I need, as an end user, was to do 2 things:
choose multiple items and 
add a custom value.

thank you though

Answer (score -2):

**Update**:  For single form, no nesting - one option is to hack together your own jquery.  I had used a different site for my testing, but this [Jquery example](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery) was the one I found easier.  I removed the stuff about a counter for max fields ... it goes in the /app/assests/javascript/.js ...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".add_field_button").click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
            $('.input_fields_wrap').append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(".input_fields_wrap").on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();
    })
});
```

And the html code ...

```
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
      <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
      <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    </div>
```

---

If you're not having luck yet - [Cocoon Gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) or railscast 197/198 will do what you need with jquery which is dynamic.  Ignore the parts about nesting and just take what you need from it.

Also, I'm still poking around in turbolinks which had an update recently...you might be able to find an answer there...probably not exactly what you would want...

From what I can tell is that is rely's on two paths you write in rails, that are then built upon via the jquery that acts on (add/delete) :before or :after the link_to_add_association or link_to_remove_association in order to add/hide fields from view on the dom & then the update button actually pushes the whole mess to through activeRecord into the database.